# Max Heap Size for Tomcat 6 on 64 bit CentOs?

Tags: java, tomcat, centos, heap-memory, ram

I am running a tomcat 6 instance on a large EC2 instance running CentOS 5.4.
The box has 7.5gb of RAM and is dedicated to running tomcat.

I am trying to give the box 6gb of RAM to use for it's max heap. However I keep getting this error:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx6144m
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
```

As I drop the amount of RAM I give it I start getting this error instead:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
```

Even with the app running (with xmx3000m) when I run free I have this amount free:

```
 [tomcat@producer1:/usr/share/tomcat/logs] $free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       7864320    1512736    6351584          0     179948     702352
-/+ buffers/cache:     630436    7233884
Swap:            0          0          0
```

The most I am able to give it is 3000m. This seems unreasonably small. Anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks

Comment: get 64bit java  :) also printing java -version helps a ton!

Comment: Are all your components 64 bit? JDK/Tomcat?

Comment: How can you check if your JVM is 64 bit?
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.3-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 3):

Do you have 64 bit JDK installed? If you are using a 32 bit JDK it can max access 4GB (theoretically).
As you are planning for 6GB, you require 64bit JDK. Added to that as you have 7.5G, 6GB is a tight no. CentOS requires some memory for kernal, processing other services, SWAP memory from this.

So give a trial & error by increasing heap size from 5G onwards. JDK requires additional memory beyond heap like permgenspace (which is typically 128M - 512M depending on how many libraries/classloaders you have)

Refer to : http://benjchristensen.com/2007/02/16/32-bit-versus-64-bit-jdk-memory-usage/